# HTML Email Outlook 2013 120DPI background

Tags: html, email, outlook, dpi

I've got an email developed and it's passing all the right tests and looks good in all the email clients I've tested (using Litmus) bar one - Outlook 2013 120DPI.

I understand what this version is doing and how it converts certain elements px units to points and scales in different ways and that's fine. However, the real issue is concerning the background image.

The table that has the background image in it requires a height to be set in order to display the content inside. So I'm setting the height to be equal to the background-image. But in this version of outlook, because the content is scaled, it's being pushed passed this height.

In all of the other email clients, this is ok, and the the content extends the table in order to fit it. But in Outlook 2013 120DPI the content is cropped. In the same manner as Overflow:hidden would but nothing like that is being set.

Any thoughts at all would be gratefully appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST TITLE</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .ReadMsgBody {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #ebebeb;
        }
        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #ebebeb;
        }
        .ExternalClass,
        .ExternalClass p,
        .ExternalClass span,
        .ExternalClass font,
        .ExternalClass td,
        .ExternalClass div {
            line-height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        table {
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .yshortcuts a {
            border-bottom: none !important;
        }


        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            table[class="columns-container"] {
                width: 320px !important;
            }

            td[class="content_mobile"] {
                width: 320px !important;
            }

            table[class="table_content_column"] {
                width: 278px !important;
            }

            td[class="content_column"] {
                width: 278px !important;
            }
            td[class="left_margin"] {
                max-width:21px !important;
                width: 21px !important;
            }

            td[class="right_margin"] {
                max-width:21px !important;
                width: 21px !important;
            }

            img[class="float"] {
                float:left !important;   
            }

        }

    </style>
    <!--[if gte mso 15]>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
    /* Outlook 2013 Height Fix */
    body { font-size: 0; line-height: 0; }
    tr { font-size:1px; mso-line-height-alt:0; mso-margin-top-alt:1px; }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->


</head>


<body style="background-color: #cdcdcd;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" width="100%" style="background-color: #cdcdcd; table-layout: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="">

                    <!-- Table Content Open -->
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="columns-container" width="600" align="center">

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="24" colspan="3">
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="content_mobile" background="email1_bg_v2.jpg" bgcolor="#000000" width="600" height="675" valign="top" colspan="3" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; align:left; background-size: 600px 675px; width:600px;height:675px;">
                                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" width="600" height="675" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:675px; background-size: 600px 675px; background-repeat: no-repeat; align:left;">
                                    <v:fill type="frame" src="email1_bg_v2.jpg" color="#000000" />
                                    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                    <![endif]-->


                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" class="columns-container">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>

                                                <!-- Left Column Padding -->
                                                <td width="60" class="left_margin">
                                                </td>


                                                <!-- Centre Column -->
                                                <td width="390" class="content_column">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="390" valign="top" class="table_content_column">

                                                        <!-- Spacer -->
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td height="60" width="390" class="content_column">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>


                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td width="390" class="content_column">
                                                                Logo Image

                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                            <!-- Spacer -->
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td height="60" width="390" class="content_column">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>


                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px;" width="390" class="content_column">
                                                                    Headline
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                            <!-- Spacer -->
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td height="30" width="390" class="content_column">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:21px;" width="390" class="content_column">
                                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br />
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                                                </td>

                                                            </tr>
                                                            <!-- Spacer -->
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td height="30" width="390" class="content_column">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>


                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>


                                                </td>

                                                <!-- Right Column Padding -->
                                                <td width="150" class="right_margin">
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                            </v:textbox>
                            </v:rect>
                            <![endif]-->

                            <!-- Footer -->
                            <tr>

                                <!-- Right Column Padding -->
                                <td height="38" width="38" bgcolor="#f3f1f1" class="left_margin">
                                </td>

                                <td height="38" width="524" bgcolor="#f3f1f1" align="right" class="content_column">

                                FOOTER LOGO

                                </td>
                                <!-- Right Column Padding -->
                                <td height="38" width="38" bgcolor="#f3f1f1" class="right_margin">
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <!-- Footer - Closed-->

                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
                    <!-- Table Content Closed -->

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *UPDATE* Actually the issue is with Outlook 2013 120DPI

Comment: Changed the title according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to properly judge the code without the actual images and content, but here's what I managed to patch up using placeholder images:

[image]

Firstly, best-practice basics. As you probably know, it's best to use background images on email where the height and width of the table cell is fixed and known, or, at least fixed but on outlook only. For example, in a header module. Your email (at least judging from the given code) breaks this rule, as you are setting background image on the whole email.

There are setting on http://backgrounds.cm to set "Single table cell" height to "Fit to content", but it's results might be inconsistent.

I can't help further with your code because code is incomplete and I can't see what you want to achieve — is it really a background image that's spanning under the content? If so, it's not worth in my opinion — the VML will load the latest, and customers won't see the background anyway for a while until it will suddenly appear in the middle of reading a broken email without a background.

As a side note, try using "Full email width" and "Fit to content" height settings on http://backgrounds.cm. It has worked for me in the past.